# Greek letters and tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, greek

I have to insert greek letters in place of V_0 and C_t but nothing seems to work. Any hint?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

% tikzstyle è deprecato: 
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/13304
\tikzset{bag/.style={text width=2em, text centered}}% align=center

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[|-stealth] (0,0) -- (8,0) node[right]{$t$};

\foreach \x/\testosopra/\testosotto in {0/V_0/{0},7/C_t/t}{
 \draw(\x,0.1)--(\x,-0.1);
 \node[above,font=\scriptsize]at (\x,0.1) (\testosopra) {$\testosopra$};
 \node[below,font=\scriptsize]at (\x,-0.1) {$\testosotto$};
}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is `(\testosopra)` in the `\draw` macro.  I think (not knowing `tikz`) that this is a node's internal label, and the conclusion is that internal labels can not be greek macros.  Here, I substitute `(\x)` for `(\testosopra)`, since internal labels like "0" and "7" are permitted.

Doing this, I have no problem then replacing `V_0` with `\alpha` and `C_t` with `\beta`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

% tikzstyle è deprecato: 
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/13304
\tikzset{bag/.style={text width=2em, text centered}}% align=center

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[|-stealth] (0,0) -- (8,0) node[right]{$t$};

\foreach \x/\testosopra/\testosotto in {0/\alpha/{0},7/\beta/t}{
 \draw(\x,0.1)--(\x,-0.1);
 \node[above,font=\scriptsize]at (\x,0.1) (\x) {$\testosopra$};
 \node[below,font=\scriptsize]at (\x,-0.1) {$\testosotto$};
}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Elisa You are welcome.  If it wholly addresses your issue in an optimal way, consider clicking the check mark to the left of my question.  That way, others will know that this is the optimal answer and I will get "credit" for it.